# Use Wordpress Login for a non-wordpress site

Tags: users, login

Please read the following example and tell me if it's possible.

Website A (wordpress) has alot of different users who must login to see some pages

Website B (non-wordpress) same as A.

Is it possible when a user makes login at wordpress to be also loged in at the non-wordpress site? I simple searching for a way not to make login two times but one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to "is possible" is almost universally yes. What matters is how your non-WordPress site functions and how difficult it would be to interface it with WordPress one.

Comment: use same user table on mysql.